# how to check latest commit of file in multiple branches

Tags: git, hash, version-control

I made few changes in one file in our repository and committed it.Now I don't remember in which branch it was. I want to find this lost branch and merge it to the master.
How do i list all the branches, and see the latest commit hash of specific file?

I except to see lots of branches with the same commit hash and one branch with different commit hash. `git log filename` gives me the latest commit hash. but how do i do it for all the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=path/to/file
for b in $(git branch | sed 's/^\*//') ; do
    echo $(git log "$b" "$file" | head -n1) " $b"
done
```

`git branch` lists all the branches, `sed` removes the asterisk (current branch) to avoid confusion. For each branch, `git log` is run for the given file, `head` extracts the first line, i.e. the commit hash.